# Valign isn't working in MDLabel in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am making practice game. I am new to kivy and kivymd. I am trying to give title at top in game screen. But it is not working

I try to set Mdlabel at top of game screen. But it is not going at top. This is my kv file.

```
<Manager>:
    Home:
    Setting:
    Help:
<Home>:
    id : first
    Screen:
        Image:
            source : "/storage/emulated/0/Ghost buster/Assest/bg.png"
            allow_stretch: True
        MDLabel:
            text: 'Ghost Buster'
            valign: 'top'
            halign:'center'
            font_style :'H3'
        MDRaisedButton:
            text: "MDRaisedButton"
           md_bg_color: "red"
           pos_hint : {'center_x' : .5 , 'center_y':.5}
```

This is my py file

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager

class Home (Screen):
    pass
class Setting (Screen):
    pass
class Help (Screen):
    pass
class Manager (ScreenManager):
    pass

class Ghost(MDApp):
    def build (self):
        return Manager()
        
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Builder.load_file ('main.kv')
    Ghost().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to fix this issue.

One is to just set the `text_size` of the `MDLabel`:

```
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Ghost Buster'
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'top'
        halign:'center'
        font_style :'H3'
```

Note that for `valign` to work, you must set `text_size`. See the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable-2.1.0/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.valign).

Another possibility is to just position the `MDLabel` where you want it:

```
    MDLabel:
        text: 'Ghost Buster'
        font_style :'H3'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1.0}
        adaptive_size: True
```